# How to update excel links after excel docs transferred from Server to Teams/Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I currently have many excel workbooks on the office server.
These contain many links between different workbooks.

We are migrating these docs over to Teams and I am doing a test.

Once in Teams (or desktop app), the link address now shows as:
=https://companyname.sharepoint.com/filepath to office server / workbook name

Q1 - why is the officer server still part of this link address?
Q2 - the link address no longer has the cell no. reference therefore I now have no idea which cell it refers to in the 2nd workbook. Is there a way to fix this?

In teams, if I click on the cell | choose 'link' | then choose the workbook that the cell relates to, then a hyperlink is created in that cell.

Clicking on that cell opens the 2nd workbook in share point, but again, I have no reference to the cell no. How can I regain references to cell numbers ?

Also, is there a way to bulk update all of these excel documents in Teams/Sharepoint?

thanks so much